# How would I display a UIDatePicker when a UITableView cell is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uidatepicker

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a `UITableView` with 5 rows. In the last two rows I want the `UILabel` to display Dates (as in a "from" date and a "to" date). When the user taps the cell I want a `UIDatePicker` to popup with a "Done" button up in the toolbar. When the user selects a date and clicks "Done", the `UIDatePicker` should close and the new date should be displayed for the `UILabel` in the cell. I have seen several examples online and here on SO that say to assign the `InputView` and `InputAccessoryView` to the date picker and toolbar containing the Done button. However, the `UILabel` is a `UIResponder` and those properties are read-only. Do I need to create my own custom `UITableViewCell` to make this work?

This seems like it should be very simple to do, and it was very simple to do something like this in my Android app. I am using Xamarin, but I can usually figure out examples in the other languages used for native iOS development as well. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "However, the UILabel is a UIResponder and those properties are read-only" Those properties are read-only, but by subclassing you get to say what their values are, so that doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I subclassed the Cell and overrode InputView and assigned the UIDatePicker like this: `public override UIView InputView => _datePicker` Nothing happens when I tap the cell though. Do I need to subclass the UILabel instead?

Comment: Presumably there is nothing that's going to _detect_ the tap. You need to detect the tap and become first responder.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I would do this or what method I could invoke maybe on "RowSelected" in my TableSource or something else?

Comment: I have an example of a date picker as an input view, but what you’re doing is not how I would do this. I would put the date picker in the table view as an accordion cell, just like in Apple’s Calendar app when you set the event start date.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to create a custom cell with textfields .

- Set the input view of the textfields to datepicker and set the toolbar with done button as input accessory view  of textfield.
- On the click of the textfields it will show datepicker.
- On the click of the done button, set the textfields text to selected date. For first time when date is not selected set the place holder text.

Is there any reason you want to use label only?

Comment: How would I subclass the UITableViewCell to use a TextView in place of the Label? I did get it working with the Label, but overriding the InputView, InputAccessoryView, CanBecomeFirstResponder, and CanResignFirstResponder properties. It effectively does the same thing as what you're suggesting though.

Comment: I have added a sample project which shows the tableview with default cell and custom cell with date picker. - https://github.com/Abhie87/SampleTableView-Datepicker